# What problems can one encode in Generalised Collatz Problem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic

The Generalised Collatz Problem asks if, given the modulus $m$ and rational coefficients $a_0,\dots,a_{m-1}$ and $b_0,\dots,b_{m-1}$ such that the transformation $T(n) := a_{n \bmod m} n + b_{n \bmod m}$ maps positive integers to positive integers, for any initial point $n_0$ there exist $i$ such that $T^i(n_0) = 1$.

Apparently (see [link](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-72504-6_49)), this problem is undecidable and moreover $\Pi_2^0$-complete. From the perspective of a working mathematician with a nodding acquaintance with logic, how big is $\Pi_2^0$ actually? In particualar, which recognisable conjectures/theorems fall into this class? Is Fermat's last theorem there? How about $abc$ conjecture? Do any statements from outside number theory/set theory/logic qualify?

Answer (score 4):

$\Pi^0_2$ is a designation in the [arithmetical hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy). Roughly speaking, a sentence is $\Pi^0_2$ if it has the form $$\forall x_1,...,x_n\in X\exists y_1,...,y_k\in Y(P(x_1,...,x_n,y_1,...,y_k))$$ where $X$ and $Y$ are "nice" countable sets (e.g. $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$) and $P$ is a "computable" property.

- **Note that this is a property of the sentence as a syntactic object**; while the usual statement of a conjecture may be at one complexity level, we may subsequently prove its equivalence with a principle at a lower complexity level. In particular, as soon as we prove a conjecture we lower its "essential complexity" substantially. :P

Many common sentences in number theory are $\Pi^0_2$ or simpler:

- Fermat's last theorem is $\Pi^0_1$: it says that for all $a,b,c,n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $n>2\rightarrow a^n+b^n\not=c^n$, and that latter property is computable in the appropriate sense. Similarly, "ZFC is consistent" asserts the non-existence of a proof of a contradiction from ZFC, and hence is $\Pi^0_1$ (we can effectively check whether something is in fact a proof of a contradiction from ZFC). Perhaps surprisingly, [the Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to a $\Pi^0_1$ sentence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31846/is-the-riemann-hypothesis-equivalent-to-a-pi-1-sentence).

  - $\Pi^0_1$ principles have a special property: their un*dis*provability in a reasonably strong system implies their *truth* - or, perhaps less mysteriously, any reasonably strong system is $\Sigma^0_1$ complete since a true $\Sigma^0_1$ fact can be established by simply presenting and analyzing an example.
- Going up one level, we hit *infinity* principles. For example, the twin prime conjecture meanwhile is $\Pi^0_2$, since being a twin prime pair is computable and TPC says "for all $n$ there is a twin prime pair $>n$." Similarly, the infinitude of Sophie Germaine primes is $\Pi^0_2$.
- But there are also natural statements beyond level $2$ - for example, the ABC conjecture. The first obvious issue is the apparent quantification over reals (the "$\epsilon$"), but that's ignorable: we can restrict attention to rational $\epsilon$s. Now the ABC conjecture has the form "For every rational $\epsilon$ there are only finitely many "bad triples,"" where being a bad triple is a computable property. "Only finitely many" has the form "$\exists \forall$," and so this formulation of the ABC conjecture is in fact $\Pi^0_3$ - a priori, too complicated! **I do not know if the ABC conjecture has a known $\Pi^0_2$ reformulation.**

---

What about *really* high-complexity principles?

Well, notice the superscript "$0$" which we haven't really touched so far. That refers to the *type* being quantified over (whereas the lower subscript refers to the number of "homogeneous blocks" of quantifiers, and the $\Pi$ vs. $\Sigma$ indicates whether the outermost quantifier is $\forall$ or $\exists$). Higher superscripts reflect quantification over higher types - e.g. the continuum hypothesis can be written as "There is a well-order of the reals with the countable predecessory property," which opens with an existential quantifier at "level $2$" *(informally the levels go: $0$ = naturals, $1$ = reals, $2$ = sets of reals, ...)* followed by what amount to quantifiers over lower types, which is to say that CH can be expressed in a $\Sigma^2_1$ way.

As we climb up these hierarchies one major question which emerges is when/how we can *remove* hypotheses from proofs: for example, could the axiom of choice be necessary to prove the Riemann hypothesis? Positive results along these lines are called **absoluteness theorems**, with one of the most important being Shoenfield's absoluteness theorem which implies that neither Choice nor CH (or their negations) can be essential to the proof of any $\Pi^1_2$ sentence (in particular, they're not going to be needed for the Riemann hypothesis).